# Django custom FileSystemStorage works in development server but not in Apache server

Tags: django, apache, django-models, django-admin, file-system-storage

I have a customized `FileSystemStorage` class to allow overwriting existent uploaded files in a subfolder of `MEDIA_ROOT` when files are uploaded via the admin change interface. However, it works fine in Django development server but in Apache no file is created when the user uploads a file and no errors are reported (neither in Apache error.log or by the Django logging system). The corresponding server folder and sub-folders have the appropriate R/W permissions for both the www-data user and group. Here is the code:

```
class MyFileStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        #pudb.set_trace()
        return name

    def _save(self, name, content):
        full_path = self.path(name)

        # Create any intermediate directories that do not exist.
        directory = os.path.dirname(full_path)
        logger = logging.getLogger('fileupload')

        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            try:
                if self.directory_permissions_mode is not None:
                    # os.makedirs applies the global umask, so we reset it,
                    # for consistency with file_permissions_mode behavior.
                    old_umask = os.umask(0)
                    try:
                        os.makedirs(directory, self.directory_permissions_mode)
                    finally:
                        os.umask(old_umask)
                else:
                    logger.debug("MyFileStorage::_save: Trying to create directory: %s" % (directory,))
                    os.makedirs(directory)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                # There's a race between os.path.exists() and os.makedirs().
                # If os.makedirs() fails with FileNotFoundError, the directory
                # was created concurrently.
                pass

        # If the file already exists we delete it, so we can re-upload a file
        # with the same filename and avoid the annoying random characters.
        if not os.path.isdir(directory):
            logger.debug("MyFileStorage::_save: IOError: %s exists and is not a directory." % directory)
            raise IOError("%s exists and is not a directory." % directory)

        if os.path.exists(full_path):
            logger.debug("MyFileStorage::_save: A file %s already exists. We remove it to avoid Django to crate a copy with random characters added to the filename." % (full_path,))
            os.remove(full_path)
        # There's a potential race condition between get_available_name and
        # saving the file; it's possible that two threads might return the
        # same name, at which point all sorts of fun happens. So we need to
        # try to create the file, but if it already exists we have to go back
        # to get_available_name() and try again.

        while True:
            try:
                # This file has a file path that we can move.
                if hasattr(content, 'temporary_file_path'):
                    logger.debug("MyFileStorage::_save: Moving the file %s to %s" % (content.temporary_file_path(), full_path))
                    file_move_safe(content.temporary_file_path(), full_path)

                # This is a normal uploadedfile that we can stream.
                else:
                    # This fun binary flag incantation makes os.open throw an
                    # OSError if the file already exists before we open it.
                    flags = (os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL |
                             getattr(os, 'O_BINARY', 0))
                    # The current umask value is masked out by os.open!
                    fd = os.open(full_path, flags, 0o666)
                    _file = None
                    try:
                        locks.lock(fd, locks.LOCK_EX)
                        for chunk in content.chunks():
                            if _file is None:
                                mode = 'wb' if isinstance(chunk, bytes) else 'wt'
                                _file = os.fdopen(fd, mode)
                                logger.debug("MyFileStorage::_save: The file %s was opened in mode '%s'." % (str(fd), mode))

                            _file.write(chunk)
                            logger.debug("MyFileStorage::_save: A chunk of information was written to the file %s." % (full_path, ))
                    finally:
                        logger.debug("MyFileStorage::_save: Closing file.")
                        locks.unlock(fd)
                        if _file is not None:
                            _file.close()
                        else:
                            os.close(fd)
            except OSError as e:
                if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
                    # A new name is needed if the file exists.
                    logger.debug("MyFileStorage::_save: The file already exists in the server. It needs a new name.")
                    name = self.get_available_name(name)
                    full_path = self.path(name)
                else:
                    logger.debug("MyFileStorage::_save: Some error occurred.")
                    raise e
            else:
                # OK, the file save worked. Break out of the loop.
                break

        if self.file_permissions_mode is not None:
            logger.debug("MyFileStorage::_save: Changing file permissions.")
            os.chmod(full_path, self.file_permissions_mode)

        # Store filenames with forward slashes, even on Windows.
        if not os.path.exists(full_path):
            logger.debug("MyFileStorage::_save: Something went wrong. The file was not created.")

        logger.debug("MyFileStorage::_save: Apparently returning normally.")
        return name.replace('\\', '/')
```

The corresponding Django model defines a FileField using this customized storage as:

```
filename = models.FileField(upload_to=get_remote_folder, blank=True, null=True, storage=MyFileStorage())
```

where:

```
def get_remote_folder(instance, filename):
    if not instance.subjectid is None:
        path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'attachments/subjects/%04d/' % (instance.subjectid.id,)        
    else:
        path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'attachments/'

    return path + filename
```

The logging file shows:

```
MyFileStorage::_save: The file 22 was opened in mode 'wb'.
MyFileStorage::_save: A chunk of information was written to the file /var/www/<app dir goes here>/uploads/attachments/subjects/0015/test_document.pdf.
MyFileStorage::_save: Closing file.
MyFileStorage::_save: Apparently returning normally.
```

Does anyone has an idea of what I'm missing?

**UPDATE**: if I manually copy a file into the folder under Apache, and I try to upload the same file, then the file is deleted from the folder (as expected since I want to overwrite a file if it has the same name) but no new file is created.

**UPDATE 2**: I ran the command `watch -n 0.1 ls` on the Apache folder and I can see that when the file is uploaded it appears listed on the screen but apparently as soon as the _save() function leaves it is deleted. That doesn't happen when the application runs on Django development server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since this seems to be some Lepricon related issue I've found a workaround (not a solution) but at least in the meanwhile it works.

The workaround consists in calling `move.file_move_safe()` on the finally block just after closing the file:

```
# We need to change the name of the file just to avoid Apache lepricons from deleting 
new_full_path = os.path.dirname(full_path) + "/_" + os.path.basename(full_path)
move.file_move_safe(full_path, new_full_path)
```

and modifying the filename in the `models.save()` method like this:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    self.filename.name = "_" + os.path.basename(self.filename.name)
    super(Files,self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

Apparently, changing the filename just after creating it prevents the Lepricons to delete it. Of course this is not the optimal solution I was looking for, but at least allows me to continue working.